# installing ios 7 on xcode 6.1 on yosemite

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

I have search a lot and comes up with lot's of different solutions and opinions which I got really confused .

I have xcode 6.1 installed with ios 8.1 simulator and I'm trying to test my apps on ios 7 . There are so many different opinions about installing ios 7 . Some says that ios 7 is not working on Yosemite and some says otherwise. also I have tried to install ios 7 from preference>devices but It got stuck and there is no progress at all with downloading.

Can anybody helps me please?Is it possible to run ios 7 on xcode 6.1 and yosemite?If so , how should I download ios 7 simulator for xcode 6.1 without using the xcode download section?maybe I can extract it from older version of xcode or download it from another source.Does upgrading to higher version of xcode helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open at Xcode `Window` menu, then `Devices` and there you can add desired simulator using little `+` button at the left bottom corner

Comment: I don't have ios 7 installed . I need to install it first

Comment: If you don's see iOS 7 option in dropdown, hit `Download more simulators` button and click to download it from the new opened window

Comment: as I mentioned in my question , That's one of my problem too. When I hit download it stucks there and there is no process at all.I'm looking for alternative ways to install that.Maybe it's possible to get extract if from older versions of xcode or I could Find download link for that.Thanks

Comment: I see ios 7 .Problem is with downloading it.

Comment: @hamid maybe you have weak Internet connection?

Comment: no ,I'm pretty sure that's not the case . I'm looking for other ways to install ios 7.1 simulator on xcode 6.1 . Do you know how ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can run iOS 7 on Xcode 6 or higher version. In order to download the iOS 7 follow the blow steps

Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Choose the iOS 7 simulator

[image]

> UPDATE

If you want to extract the iOS sdks from older version go to the terminal and follow below and then restart the xCode.

```
cp -r SOURCE_PATH DESTINATION_PATH
```

for example

```
cp -r /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

Comment: the problem with this way is that when I click download the process bar display and stuck there without any progress. So , I'm wondering if there is other way to download IOS 7.1 simulator ?Maybe it's possible to extract it from older xcodes or download it from another source ? Thanks .

Comment: Is your machine connected to the internet. because me and my fellow colleague never faced this problem. And yes you can extract it from older version of Xcode.

Comment: ,Could you tell me how to extract it from older verson of Xcode please? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 7.0 Simulator Runtime is not supported on OS X Yosemite.

The iOS 7.1 Simulator Runtime is supported on OS X Yosemite.

Install Xcode 6.2 and navigate to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads, and you will be given the option to install the iOS 7.1 Simulator Runtime.  It will install below /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator.

Note that some versions of Xcode have a bug where the download will not occur if your laptop is running on battery.  I do not know of the top of my head which versions of Xcode are affected.  If the download progress isn't moving forward, go connect to AC.